# Qt Creator's interface AND my Qt app's interface shows gargantuan fonts in toolbars - how to resolve?

Tags: qt-creator

Intermittently, while programming using Qt Creator, the Qt Creator interface appears with garantuan, unusably huge fonts for the text in toolbars and other elements.

I am attaching a screenshot.

[image: Qt Creator's fonts are gargantuan]

This issue only happens intermittently, but I cannot find any hint of this problem when searching via Google, and I cannot understand why it is happening or what to do about it.

I am using a high-resolution monitor (4K, 2160 x 3840) with Windows 10; the Windows setting for "*Change the size of text, apps, and other items*" is set to 100% in the Settings - and I have not noticed any other applications with this problem (except perhaps once or twice in the past and I think the application must have been built with Qt - but I do not remember).

How do I resolve the issue of Qt Creator displaying gargantuan fonts in various elements of its user interface?

---

Edit: The issue is even more severe than I thought.  Now, the application I am **building** in Qt has the same problem.  Here is a screenshot:

[image: Even my own Qt app's fonts are intermittently gargantuan!]

What is going on here?  Obviously, although the problem is intermittent for me, I am concerned that my client might suddenly have the problem appear.

I do **not** think the solution is for me to set the font size for my widgets with a stylesheet.  Usually, this problem does not occur, and I am think this is a bug with Qt - not with my code.

What can I do to prevent this?